# How to clear the fields of ionic alert?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, alert

```js
<IonAlert
                        isOpen={isDeleteOpen}
                        inputs={[
                          {
                            name: 'password',
                            type: 'password',
                            placeholder: 'Password do escaneador',
                          },
                        ]}
                        buttons={[
                          {
                            text: 'Cancelar',
                            role: 'cancel',
                            handler: () => {},
                          },
                          {
                            text: 'Apagar de vez!',
                            cssClass: 'alert-delete-btn',
                            handler: (inputs) => {
                              deleteImage(inputs.password);
                              inputs.password = '';
                              return null;
                            },
                          },
                        ]}
                      />
```

How to clear the ionic alert input field ? I cannot delete fields.
Is there such function or attribute.

Dont find anything in the docs.

The fields keep with values inside. after closing the alert.
When I open again , the previous are still there. I want to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did (Angular project): each time I open the ionic alert, I clear the value of the input by retrieving it with its id.

**alert inputs**:

```
public readonly alertInputs: AlertInput[] = [
    {
        id: "passwordInput",
    },
];
```

**open method**:

```
public openDialog() {
      this.isOpen = true;
      const input = document.getElementById("passwordInput");
      if (input) {
        input.value = "";
      }
}
```